# Crystal report not showing all data

Tags: crystal-reports

Created a stored procedure which i pushed to my crystal report. The thing is some fields are showing blank even though data is returned in the query. I have retested the query, Verify the database over and over but nothing

Comment: can you provide more information? what fields are in query and what fields are in report?

Comment: All the fields from the query are in the report just that no data comes. I have fields repairdate, repairtype, repaircost and repair. Repaircost and type are the only 2 that comes up with data in the report. The others are blank even though when I run the SP in Sql Server data appears in all fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help but I figured out the problem. I had a join on 2 tables that have the same field names which I did not rename in the query. The 2 fields that weren't showing were the ones that are similar. I renamed those fields in the select statement and my data is now showing [silly me :)]